# Variable not getting through to middleware function

Tags: node.js, express

I have a bug which has made me realize I clearly missing something important about express middlewares. I have something like this:

```
const checkAuth = ({ allowedRoles = [], targetUserId }) => {
   return async (req, res, next) => { 
      console.log(targetUserId);
      //Do checks
      if(!allowedRoles.includes(req.user.role) return
      targetUserId = req.params[targetUserId]
      if(!allowedUsers.includes(targetUserId) return

      return next();
   };
};
 
app.get(
   "/activity/:id",
   checkAuth({ allowedRoles: ["locationAdmin", "orgAdmin"], targetUserId: "id" }),
   async function (req, res, next) {
      //Do things
   });
});
```

The idea behind this middleware is the 'targetUserId'variable tells it which request parameter to look in for a value, then it can choose to authorize the request with the value it finds there. The middleware actually exists in it's own file/module if that makes any difference.

Here's what I expect to happen:

1. User loads url /activity/23   > "id" is logged
2. User loads url /activity/23   > "id" is logged
   and so on until the end of time...

What actually happens:

1. User loads url /activity/23   > "id" is logged
2. User loads url /activity/23   > 23 is logged
3. User loads url /activity/23   > undefined is logged
4. User loads url /activity/23   > null is logged
   item 4 will then repeat forever

My expectation is that each time checkAuth is called, there should be nothing in memory from it's last call. It's taken me a couple of hours to get my head around this, but what seems to be happening, is after the value of targetUserId is set within the middleware, the variable remains set in memory, and isn't changed when it gets called again with "id". This explains why the value logged to the console changes 3 times on repeat requests for the same page.

But why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your middleware needs to either call `next()` or send a response to the request.  Lines of code like this: `if(!allowedRoles.includes(req.user.role) return` are doing neither.  That will just hang the incoming request until it eventually times out.

Comment: The way you register your middleware with `checkAuth({ allowedRoles: ["locationAdmin", "orgAdmin"], targetUserId: "id" })`, that function is called only once at server initialization time and it returns a middleware function that is then registered as middleware on this route and the `targetUserid` property is set once and used by the middleware function that returns for all future requests it is called for.  It's not clear what else you're asking or expecting with that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah yes that's really helpful. I was forgetting that the middleware function is only called at server initialization, not when a call to the route is made. In this situation, I should be making sure I don't modify the value of anything passed into that function on initialization and my bug will go.

Comment: Slight terminology issue here.  Your `checkAuth()` function is a regular function that returns a middleware function.   The `checkAuth()` function is only called once and it's arguments are saved for future use.  The middleware function that it returns is called multiple times for each new incoming request that matches this route.  Any checkAuth()` arguments that are objects are passed by pointer so if you later change the original object that change will affect the middleware when it executes in the future.

Comment: The code you show here in this question does not have that vulnerability of changing the arguments later because you're passing an anonymous object (no external reference saved) that can't be referenced outside of `checkAuth()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is structured, `checkAuth()` is called once when your code is first run.  That captures the arguments you passed it and then makes those available to the middleware function that `checkAuth()` returns and that middleware function is passed to Express where it is registered as middleware for this request handler.

That middleware function you return is then called by Express for each incoming request that matches this request handler.  The arguments you passed to `checkAuth()` are available to that middleware function each time it is called.

If some code changes those arguments (like code inside the middleware itself changes an object or property passed), then those changes are persistent (in a closure) and future middleware will see those changes.  So, if you need to modify those arguments for the purposes of one request, then you should make a copy of the data or make the modifications in a variable that is local to the internal middleware function.